# How to use only the first few characters of an entry in a list to compare to another list - python

Tags: python, sorting

Sorry for the title gore.... So I have 2 lists, one of parts names and one is a shortened list of parts. I am trying to see if an entry in list B exists in the first few characters of an entry in list A. if it does, then output the entry of list A.

This is what I've been working with thus far:

```
    index = 0
    for x in data2:
        if x in Part_List[index][:8]:
            print ("nanners")
            d = Part_List[index]
            index += 1
        else:
            return
```

EDIT: 
data2 = ['12345678', '23456789', '34567890']

Part_List = ['12345678 - Nanners', '23456789 - Nannu Nannu', '34567890 - ROFL Stomp']

Comment: Could you give us an example of such lists?

Comment: @pacholik see edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way you can use:

```
part_list = {'lorem':1,'ipsum':2,'dolor':3}
list1 = ['loremx','ipsumxx','dolorxxx']

for x in list1:
    for key in part_list.keys():
        if x[:4] == key[:4]:
            print x,key,part_list[key]
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Considering both are lists:

```
data2 = ['12345678', '23456789', '34567890']
part_list = ['12345678 - Nanners', '23456789 - Nannu Nannu', '34567890 - ROFL Stomp']
for b in data2:
    for part in part_list:
        if b in part :
            print part
```

Answer (score 0):

List of number-part tuples using one list comprehention:

```
[(number, part) for number in data2 for part in Part_List if part.startswith(number)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data2 = ['12345678', '23456789', '34567890']
Part_List = ['12345678 - Nanners', '23456789 - Nannu Nannu', '34567890 - ROFL Stomp']
```

Using list comprehension:

```
print ([text for subtext in data2 for text in Part_List if text.startswith(subtext)])
```

The normal way:

```
for subtext in data2:
    for text in Part_List:
        if text.startswith(subtext):
            print (text)
```